# how to change the data type from string to bytes, keeping the contents of the string unchanged?

Tags: numpy, pickle

How can you convert string to bytes? And it's not about decode/encode, I have just bytes in the string, I just need to convert the format of the string to bytes.

The point is that I want to write the array numpy in the image metadata. In order to save both the shape of the array and its contents I use the pickle package, but in the image metadata can be written only a string, so I convert the pickle object to a string by simple srt(). such data are written and read from the image metadata look the same as the bits but in string format:
b'\x80\x04\x95\xaa\x00\x00\x00...
Now for pickle to be able to convert this data to numpy array I need to return it to type (bytes), but how can I do that? Everyone on the internet is talking about converting strings to bytes and vice versa via decode/encode, but that's not what I need

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you show some code.

[`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) returns a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) object; ideally you would be able to write this straight to your image metadata without the `str`; investigate if you can write metadata in "binary" mode.  If that is not an option, I suggest looking at [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#module-base64) encoding.

If you insist on using the `str` method, you could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to somewhat safely convert back to a bytes object.

This sample demonstrates binary and `str` and `ast.literal_eval`

```py
import ast
import pickle

import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1.23, np.pi], [3, 4]])

# binary mode
with open('data.bin', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(pickle.dumps(a))

with open('data.bin', 'rb') as infile:
    b = pickle.loads(infile.read())

print('binary')
print(b)
print(f'{(a==b).all() = }')

# ast.literal_eval hack
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(pickle.dumps(a)))

with open('data.txt') as infile:
    c = pickle.loads(ast.literal_eval(infile.read()))

print()
print('str & ast.literal_eval')
print(c)
print(f'{(c==b).all() = }')
```

On my system (Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.9.7 via Conda), this gives:

```
binary
[[1.23       3.14159265]
 [3.         4.        ]]
(a==b).all() = True

str & ast.literal_eval
[[1.23       3.14159265]
 [3.         4.        ]]
(c==b).all() = True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the ast option worked. Unfortunately only a string can be written to the metadata, if it were possible to write bytes, there would be no question